# Populate Combobox VB from SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, combobox

I have two tables in a SQL Server database. After linking my VB project to the database, I want to fill a combobox with values from a certain table. How I should do this?

For example, let's suppose I have a table with `id` and `name` columns. The combobox shows the list of names found in the table. If I select a certain name here, how can I insert the id of that name into another table?

Comment: [How to load combobox from SQL query in .net?](http://vb.net-informations.com/dataset/bind-combobox.htm) but your question is to insert data into a database table using combobox value?

Answer (score 0):

use **DisplayMember** and **ValueMember** properties

```
cboData.DataSource = dsClients.Clients
cboData.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboData.ValueMember = "ID"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
but what do you mean by dsclients.clients

Comment: dsClients probably refers to a dataset with a method to get Clients.